# How to pass token from Nodejs to backend Java code

Tags: node.js, spring-mvc, jwt

I am new to Nodejs .
I am trying to pass JWT token from Nodejs to java service class.
I am getting JWT token in a variable in Nodejs code that I need to pass to spring mvc application service class.

can anyone please help me on this?
And having confusion with how to integrate Nodejs with java if i pass variable from Nodejs to java?

Node code is,

```
module.exports = {
  verifyReq: function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.headers.authorization) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
      res.write('<div id="_mscontent"><script src="URL"></script>');
      var notAuthorized = false;
      var authorization = req.headers.authorization;
      console.log("authorization: " + authorization);

      if (authorization) {
        req.isAuthorized = true;
      }
      try {
        var decodedJWT = JWT.decode(authorization.split(' ')[1], "", true);
      } catch (e) {
        notAuthorized = true;
      }
      else {
      req.isAuthorized = false;
      res.status(401); 
      res.end('Not Authorized!');
      return;
    }
   return req.isAuthorized === true;
  }
};
```

Java Code,

```
public class GetCarAssetValuesService {
    private static String output;
    private static String token;
    private static Asset[] myObjects;

    public void getAssets(String tokenToPass)
            throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException, JSONException {
        System.out.println("In service");
        HttpsURLConnection myURLConnection = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(tokenToPass);
        System.out.println("success_token= " + jsonObj);
        token = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
        System.out.println("Print token= " + token);
        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "Third Party URL");
            myURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            String bearerAuth = "Bearer " + token;
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", bearerAuth);
            myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            inputStream = myURLConnection.getInputStream();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            if (myURLConnection.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + myURLConnection.getResponseCode());
            }
            System.out.println("Here the control cars...");
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                strBuilder.append(output);
                System.out.println(output);
            }
            myURLConnection.disconnect();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String mindsphereResponse = strBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println("Responsesssssss" + mindsphereResponse);

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        myObjects = mapper.readValue(mindsphereResponse, Asset[].class);

    }
```

Here instead of passing "tokenToPass" i want to get this token from node js i.e.decodeJWT. This "tokenToPass" i am getting from other java service now i want it from Nodejs.

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the JWT token in the HTTP Request header ( nodejs ) and API endpoint ( java ) can be get it from there.

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowire
    private HomeService homeService;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String home(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        helloService.invoke(request.getHeader('JWT_TOKEN_KEY'));
}
}
```

HelloService.java

```
@Service
public class HelloService {

    public void invoke(jwtToken) {
       // Use this jwttoken
}
}
```

NodeJS.js

```
var options = {
  host: 'your_java_api_endpoint',
  port: 80,
  path: '/hello',
  headers:{
    'JWT_TOKEN_KEY':'json web token here'
  }
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  res.on("data", function(responseData) {
    console.log("data: " + responseData);
  });
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("http error : " + e);
});
```

Comment: i have added my node code there i am getting token in variable named "decodeJWT". Could you please help me how to proceed further.

Comment: Share your java code as well and where in the nodejs you are calling java api.

Comment: i am not getting how call java api in node ...as i am new to Nodejs....i just want to use this jwt token in service class where i am calling third party api and for calling that api i need to pass this token as authorization header.

Comment: you cannot call java method from nodejs you have to expose an java api endpoint that can be called from nodejs. Reference links for calling api from nodejs - https://www.rapiddg.com/blog/calling-rest-api-nodejs-script , https://codeburst.io/how-to-make-an-http-request-in-nodejs-http-mechanism-libraries-f25ec990d307

Comment: Thank you so much for quick response....i have added my java code there i am calling third party url for accessing that i need jwt token that token i need from nodejs. curently i am getting token from same another java service class but i want it from Nodejs...kindly help on this.....Thanks in Advance

Comment: @aaa I have update the answer to call http request from nodejs and get the required data in java

Comment: how to integrate this node.js file with java ...is this understanding is correct..i need to create seperate node js project and seperate java file?

Comment: you have to run seprate nodejs project

Comment: Thank you so much....have one more doubt, in my project i am having multiple controllers and i want to use this token for multiple service class....how could i do this?

Comment: Spring  has a concept of `interceptors` that can be called on each and every api call. You can set the data in this layer and any services in your java code can get from it. Follow this example for more clarity - https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-interceptor.html